# How to set groups "Recommended by the admins" in a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I found a Facebook group showing groups "Recommended by the admins". I would like to use it, but I do not understand how.

[image: The feature "Recommended by the admins"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/119363955383676):

> If you're a group admin, you can recommend other groups by linking
>   them to your group. You can only link groups you admin.
>
> To link a group:
>
> 1. Go to your group and click  below the cover photo.
> 2. Select **Link Existing Group** to link a group you already admin, or select **Create New Linked Group**.
> 3. Search for the group's name then click **Link**. If you create a new linked group, choose a group name and privacy setting and then
>      click **Create**.
> 4. After the group is linked, you'll have the option to write a post about it.

Comment: When I posted the question, this was not available for my 3000 members group. Now the feature is available.

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Link existing group" in the dropdown you posted a screenshot of above. When you link your group, it will show in the "Recommended by the Admins" section.

Answer (score -2):

Group should have at least 5000 members before you can have that function. Cheers

Comment: People who downvoted: can you explain me why?

Answer (score -2):

It appears this feature was removed.

Comment: You're wrong about your answer, it still exists. And it would be better for next time if you'll improve your answers and add references when needed.